# Enumeration of flat integral $K_4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

**Question:**

> What is known about the enumeration of all $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\mathbb{N}^6_+: \\ \quad\operatorname{GCD}(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1\ \\ \land\ \exists \lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\rbrace\subset\mathbb{E}^2:\ \\ \quad \lbrace \|x_j-x_i\| \rbrace_{1\le i\lt j\le 4}=\lbrace a,b,c,d,e,f\rbrace$

Comment: The term "flat" in the title was chosen instead of "planar" because of the ambigous meaning of the latter when dealing with graph theory and geometry in the same context.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}^2$? Is it $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @GHfromMO its the euclidean plane; I have seen that notation frequently. Using $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the euclidean plane necessitates losing words about the distance metric.

Comment: Regarding the notation for the Euclidean plane see e.g. [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane). It may be debatable if $\boldsymbol{E}^2$ and $\mathbb{E}^2$ are both acceptable.